# Add a "default tag" feature?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Looking through a lot of the PHP questions, I see a lot of questions that use deprecated features like mysql_query. Usually this ends up with at least 2 comments on the question somewhere along the lines of:

```
Don't use mysql_* - the functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead
```

How about a "default tag" feature? So basically, they'd work like tags where users with enough karma could create/modify, and then users could hit a "Add Default Tag" link that was shown on a question that needed it. That would bring up a modal with all of the default tags where users could pick a relevant tag.

Would this not lead to a better commenting/discussion on S.O. questions?

Comment: But that's usually *not* an answer to the question. It's good advice for the future, but doesn't solve *their* problem.

Comment: I don't think anything should be automated. Comments like that are welcome but an automated reply will do more harm than good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Don't use mysql_* - the functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead

Most of the time, an answer like this would actually be pretty bad. It *should* be a comment, and not an answer. Good answers should be **correct** and **complete**, not just general tips for the asker. Perhaps the asker is stuck with using `mysql_query` for some reason; an answer like this this wouldn't actually address their issue, even it is a good suggestion.

Even if there was a good 'default' answer you could apply to many questions that would be correct and complete, it's likely those questions should be closed as duplicates.

I don't see how a feature like this would add any great value to the site.

On the other hand, having the ability to post some default comments *is* quite useful. It's not something that's likely to be built into SO any time soon, but there are other options. If you'd like to be able to more easily add prepared, template-based comments to answers, I'd recommend you check out the excellent [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) user script on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). In fact, it appears at [someone's already using](https://stackapps.com/a/3727) it for exactly these kinds of comments!

Comment: Adding on this: if there was more than one question for which the answer *does* apply; then all but one of the questions should be closed for being a duplicate *anyway*.